# cyclic permutation in O(1) space and O(n) time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic, permutation

I saw an interview question which asked to

`Interchange arr[i] and i for i=[0,n-1]`

EXAMPLE :
 input : `1 2 4 5 3 0`
 answer :`5 0 1 4 2 3`

explaination : `a[1]=2 in input , so a[2]=1 in answer so on`

I attempted this but not getting correct answer.

what i am able to do is : `for a pair of numbers p and q , a[p]=q and a[q]=p .`

any thoughts how to improve it are welcome.

```
FOR(j,0,n-1)
{
    i=j;
    do{
        temp=a[i];
        next=a[temp];
        a[temp]=i;
        i=next;
    }while(i>j);
}
print_array(a,i,n);
```

It would be easier for me to to understand your answer if it contains a pseudocode with some explaination.

**EDIT :** I came to knpw it is cyclic permutation so changed the question title.

Comment: The question is not ambitious enough: if you can solve it in O(1) space then you can solve it in O(1) time too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is what I came up with (Java code).

For each value `x` in `a`, it sets `a[x]` to `x`, and sets `x` to the overridden value (to be used for `a[a[x]]`), and repeats until it gets back to the original `x`.

I use negative values as a flag to indicate that the value's already been processed.

**Running time:**

Since it only processes each value once, the running time is `O(n)`.

**Code:**

```
int[] a = {1,2,4,5,3,0};
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
   if (a[i] < 0)
      continue;
   int j = a[i];
   int last = i;
   do
   {
      int temp = a[j];
      a[j] = -last-1;
      last = j;
      j = temp;
   }
   while (i != j);
   a[j] = -last-1;
}
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
   a[i] = -a[i]-1;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Comment: Nice Idea! I couldn't think of a way to keep track of items already processed.

Comment: @Dukeling i understood most part of your code . Just one doubt : `can't we use -last instead of -last-1 ?`  
is it to make  `0 => -1 because flag should be -ve ?`

Comment: @aseemgoyal Yes, it's because of 0 that it's `-last-1`. Using `-last` and then `if (a[i] <= 0)` (and obviously `a[i] = -a[i];`) would also work, but understanding why it would is a bit more difficult - you can get a 0-valued element, but only if either (1) `a[0] = 0`, in which case we can skip it, or (2) we're at the end of a cycle that started at `i=0`, in which case we'll get it inside the do-while loop, where `a[i] <= 0` isn't checked. All-in-all, just make it strictly negative and don't worry about all that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion, `O(n)` time, `O(1)` space:

```
void OrderArray(int[] A)
{
    int X = A.Max() + 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        A[i] *= X;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        A[A[i] / X] += i;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        A[i] = A[i] % X;
}
```

A short explanation:

We use `X` as a basic unit for values in the original array (we multiply each value in the original array by `X`, which is larger than any number in `A`- basically the length of `A` + 1). so at any point we can retrieve the number that was in a certain cell of the original array by array by doing `A[i] / X`, as long as we didn't add more than `X` to that cell.

This lets us have two layers of values, where `A[i] % X` represents the value of the cell after the ordering. these two layers don't intersect through the process.

When we finished, we clean `A` from the original values multiplied by `X` by performing `A[i] = A[i] % X`.

Hopes that's clean enough.

Comment: Your code works magically for all the test cases I have tried.

Comment: Can you please explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is possible by using the images of the input permutation as indices:

```
 void inverse( unsigned int* input, unsigned int* output, unsigned int n )
 {
     for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
         output[ input[ i ] ] = i;
 }
```

Comment: you are using EXTRA space , which is not allowed

Comment: Please clarify: is the input permutation permitted to contain more than one cycle? In the title is says "cyclic permutation", but the counterexample to Abhishek Bansal's code contains two cycles.